# How to delete the Crestron Audio Device in Mac

Tags: mac, drivers

I install Crestron - and it installed a audio device called "Crestron Audio". I can't seem to get rid of it.

what I have done till now

check /Library/Extensions, /Library/Audio and other suggestion location from my internet searches. I can't find the com.crestron.CrestronAudioPlugin to delete.

Any help please.. how do I delete this audio device from Mac

I [image]

Comment: What is your exact version of macOS?

Comment: How far did you explore in `/Library/Audio`? I'm seeing evidence it's installed in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL`.

Comment: Darwin srirams-mac 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jan 23 06:52:12 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.25~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

also did a full system search - but will look at HAL also now

Comment: @Spiff thanks - I couldn't find it the first time.. so, based on some other recommendation, I reinstalled the software, found the driver in HAL, uninstalled the software, then removed the driver, rebooted, and it fixed it. you rock !!!

Comment: @Spiff if you want to answer the question, I can mark it as complete.

Comment: I think you should post your own solution as an Answer and then accept your own Answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @spiff.

some of the drivers were missing from a previous installer.

I also reazlied from @spiff's message that all the "audio devices" are listed in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL`

so, did a reinstall, found the driver in /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL and cleaned it up.

thanks